# Debugging Internet Explorer in windbg

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, windbg

I was doing some crash analysis using windbg. Suppose the stack trace indicates the crash is at mshtml!CBase::put_String ,is there a way to figure out what javascript or DOM manipulation leads to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack you can sometimes make a pretty good guess.  Since you only get public symbols you don't have the ability to easily get detailed information about the internal state of the objects.  If you post your whole stack I may be able to help you figure it out.

If there is some identifying characteristic, you may be able to call the getter.  You can use .call to do that.  See [Raymonds post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/27/2292037.aspx) describing .call.

If you think you've found a real bug in IE, you can always post it to http://connect.microsoft.com/ie for the IE team to have a look at.  Be sure to include a link to the site or minimal HTML repro...